# Instrumentation not working for methods invoked through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am tracing the execution of Java applications to perform dynamic analysis on the execution traces.

Everything is fine but when a method is called through reflection. I can see the invocation of `Method.invoke` but after that my trace does not contain the instructions executed through reflection.

As soon as the program goes back to 'regular' execution the program get traced again normally.

The person who wrote the instrumentor used the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library.

Comment: You can use ASM to get the parameters of `Method.invoke`. If you are open to this, I will post an answer.

Comment: I should be able to read the `Method.invoke` parameters, but that would solve my issue only partially. I will still miss the call tree generated by the method invoked through reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. The problem was not related to the instrumentation but to the configuration of the tool which by the way is [open source](http://code.google.com/p/trace-synthesis-collector/).

Instrumentation worked properly because it worked by modifying the byte-code of the methods. Have a look at the code of the project to see how instrumentation should be done.